# Raw coding vs Joomla / Drupal

Tags: cms, joomla, drupal, performance

Currently my sites pages load in about 500ms.  The HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Perl, and SQL queries are totally not optimised.  If I recreate the site using Joomla, will my site slow down?

Comment: "Currently my sites pages load in about 500ms." So are you using a CMS at present (Drupal?) or is the content you're talking about just static HTML plus stylesheets, scripts, and multimedia files..?

Comment: I am not using a CMS yet.  All my pages a coded via php and generated mostly via several sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there would be a difference in speed.

Some CMS/Frameworks have more streamlined SQL queries, but the speed in which a CMS delivers its pages isn't noticeable. The noticeable advantage of a CMS is the security it provides when querying the database. Things like images and JavaScript files impact on page delivery times more than a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage a CMS could offer you is caching - "saving" page HTML for a few minutes, hours, or days so users who aren't logged in get these saved pages, instead of pages that execute all the database queries every time a page is loaded.  In addition to page caching, there are also other mechanisms available for caching parts of pages.

500ms is a very long time for a pageload.  I would suggest you find professional help, since it sounds like you are using a lot of different technologies and are in a rather complicated situation.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is known for being a little slower than other CMS. But there are some ways to make it faster, it really depends on your configuration.
I don´t know Joomla.